# Changing properties in IE using JQuery; changes only applied when debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a simple script that's run at load from a separate js file.
The setup is like this:

```
    var ddlPeriodeVan = $('[id$=ddlPeriodeVan]');
    var ddlPeriodeTot = $('[id$=ddlPeriodeTot]');
    chkPeriodeVanTot = $('[id$=chkPeriodeVanTot]').length > 0 ? $('[id$=chkPeriodeVanTot]') : $('[id$=rbPeriodeVanTot]');
    var periodeBereik = { van: 'ddlPeriodeVan', tot: 'ddlPeriodeTot', err: 'ddlPeriode', chk: chkPeriodeVanTot, label: 'Periode' };
    if (ddlPeriodeVan.length > 0 && ddlPeriodeTot.length > 0) {
        if (chkPeriodeVanTot.length > 0) {
            chkPeriodeVanTot.change(periodeBereik, changedCheckNummerBereik);

            if (chkPeriodeVanTot.prop('checked')) { // checkbox aangevinkt, maak de waardevelden bewerkbaar
                ddlPeriodeVan.prop('disabled', false).prop('readonly', false).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
                ddlPeriodeTot.prop('disabled', false).prop('readonly', false).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            } else { // Disable en readonly aanzetten, achtergrond blauw en tekst op (leeg indien textbox / defaultwaarde indien dropdown)
                // The debugger actually gets here and changes the properties correctly
                // When there is no breakpoint, the changes have no effect
                // When there is a breakpoint, the changes are made and remain visible
                ddlPeriodeVan.prop('disabled', true).prop('readonly', true).css('background-color', '#AACAF4');
                ddlPeriodeTot.prop('disabled', true).prop('readonly', true).css('background-color', '#AACAF4');
            }
        }
```

At initial page_load, `chkPeriodeVanTot` is not checked and `ddlPeriodeVan` and `ddlPeriodeTot` should be disabled, readonly and have a different background color.

This works fine in other browsers (of course), but IE thinks differently about this and I don't know why.

The weird thing is, when I the developer tools in IE11 and set a breakpoint in the file. The breakpoint gets hit and the code ddl's are changed as expected!
Does IE refresh the DOM somewhere so that all changes are lost?

**EDIT**

I figured out that setting a breakpoint isn't even necessary. Just having the F12 developer tools window open does the trick. Everything loads correctly.
Closing F12 and refreshing breaks it again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I've got some Microsoft logic right here:

In all "modern" browsers, window.console is created even if you don't have the debugger open. For IE, window.console is `undefined` if the debugger is closed.

An internal error of which you will never see it being thrown is causing all your scripts to stop executing...

So don't use window.console (you shouldn't in production code) or check if console is undefined before using it.